# system volume is changed when vlc volume is increased over 100%

Tags: fedora, gnome, audio, vlc

When I increase my vlc sound more than 100% and after stoping or pausing vlc if I use clementine to play music the volume is same as vlc, i.e, more than 100% but in the indicator it shows whatever the previous set state, is this a bug? if so bug of vlc/clementine/gnome-shelll?

using fedora 17, gnome-shell, latest vlc and clementine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, VLC doesn't change IT'S volume. It changes SYSTEM'S volume. So it is not a bug, it's designed to be that way.

VLC -> Volume(GNOME) -> Speakers

Clementine -> Volume(Clementine) -> Volume(GNOME) -> Speakers

Comment: This isn't the case on my system. VLC adjusts its own volume, but `flat-volumes` causes the sink volume to be adjusted too. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a "feature" of PulseAudio.

```
; flat-volumes = yes (default)
flat-volumes = no
```

Flat volumes raises the sink volume so that it is no less than that of the loudest application. For more information, see `pulse-daemon.conf(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug I'm sure, as it increases the systems volume but doesn't decrease it.

To verify just set the volume to 30 in fedora, then set volume to 90 in vlc, check fedora's volume, it's the same, then set vlc to 50, check fedora, volume is still at 90...

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of how this works in-depth, but if you adjust the volume in the full-blown sound menu (at least for gnome), you'll find the system volume itself goes over 100%, and VLC adjusts system volume, not it's own (personally, I think it's simpler that way, though if it's a huge deal to you, I'm sure there's an option somewhere to adjust its volume relative to the system)